# Как вывести последнее непустое значение по строке?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет, есть таблица. Как вывести в отдельный столбец последнее не пустое значение по строке?

| id | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Последнее не пустое |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null | null | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | null | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 6 | 6 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | 7 | 7 |

Comment: Выражение с IF или CASE

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey, как сделать отдельный столбец я понимаю. Проблема в том, что не понимаю, как выбрать последнее не пустое значение)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(Col3, Col2, Col1) AS [Последнее не пустое]
FROM
(
VALUES  (1, 1, NULL, NULL),
        (2, 1, 5, NULL),
        (3, 1, 2, 6),
        (4, 5, 1, 7)
) AS MyTable(Id, Col1, Col2, Col3)
```

Comment: Мне нравится! Поздравляю с 1к)

Comment: @AndrewNikolaev еее, благодарю))

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin, а если данные другие в таблице и она постоянно увеличивается. Такой метод будет подходить только для конкретной таблицы, которая в примере.

Comment: @sk1p96 Какой вопрос- такой ответ)
На счёт "а если столбцы будут увеличиваться" Андрей Николаев уже ответил: понадобится динамический SQL применять

Answer (score 1):

Я могу такой вариант, но он для статичного набора колонок. Для динамического состава колонок потребуется динамический запрос.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (ID INT IDENTITY, Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT)

INSERT INTO #Test(Col1, Col2, Col3) 
VALUES 
    (1, NULL, NULL),
    (1, 5, NULL),
    (1, 2, 6),
    (5, 1, 7)
    
SELECT *,
    LastNoEmpty = CASE 
                    WHEN Col3 IS NOT NULL THEN Col3 
                    WHEN Col2 IS NOT NULL THEN Col2
                    WHEN Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN Col1
                    ELSE NULL
                  END 
FROM #Test t 

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Comment: ELSE NULL - лишнее

Comment: Это для полноты конструкции, а так конечно не обязательно писать)

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение.

Оно работает независимо от количества рассматриваемых столбцов. Без всякого динамического SQL.

Оно использует XML и XQuery. Если столбец имеет значение NULL, то при преобразовании в XML такой столбец пропускается в `CROSS APPLY`. Именно то, что нам нужно.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, начало
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, col_1 int, col_2 INT, col_3 int);
INSERT @tbl (col_1, col_2, col_3) VALUES
(1, NULL, NULL),
(1, 5, NULL),
(2, 2, 6),
(5, 1, 7);
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, конец

SELECT t1.*
    , c.value('(/root/*[local-name()!="id"][last()]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS [Последнее не пустое]
FROM @tbl AS t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM @tbl AS t2
    WHERE t1.id = t2.id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t3(c);
```

**Результат**

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+---------------------+
| id | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | Последнее не пустое |
+----+-------+-------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 |     1 | NULL  | NULL  |                   1 |
|  2 |     1 | 5     | NULL  |                   5 |
|  3 |     2 | 2     | 6     |                   6 |
|  4 |     5 | 1     | 7     |                   7 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Браво! Топ ответ. Надеюсь автор вопроса действительно использует MS SQL Server.

Comment: С точки зрения производительности не всё так хорошо как на вид. CROSS APPLY будет для каждой строки строить XML(что много по символам), а в SELECT эти данные будут выбираться из XML, что тоже просаживает.  В то время как динамический SQL соберёт все столбцы 1 раз и далее, внутри COALESCE будет вычисляться значение привычным для РСУБД способом. Решение интересное, но я бы переписал его на динамический аналог.

Comment: Пожалуйста, проголосуйте за мое предложение: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky поддержал. Спасибо за наводку, как раз обнаружил недостающий функционал и запилил предложение. Если не сложно, поддержите: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/e70a91e8-f917-ed11-a81b-6045bd853198

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin, поддержал.